# Wordpress responsive issue

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I just uploaded a site that I've been working on locally and got some unexpected glitches that I'm not too sure how to fix, nor do I know why they happened.

The reponsiveness of the blog page [here](http://www.chrisbattenandthewoods.com/blog),works fine when you shrink the browser on our desktop, but if you look at it on a phone, it is not responsive at all. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your phone has something what is called a Viewport. This is probably what makes it look bad.

Try adding this meta-tag:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, user-scalable=no">
```

Check this link to get more info about those viewports: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Mozilla/Mobile/Viewport_meta_tag

Comment: Ah man, awesome! Thanks. I used a blank theme and just never realized that tag wasn't in there. Thanks again!